# Shrink sticky header with logo by adding a class?

Tags: html, css, css-animations, sticky

I've got a header and add a class `is-sticky` when scroll-position of the page is greater than 0.

This header contains an img with my logo.
I'd like to shrink the height INCLUDING the one of the `img` when that class is added.

How can I do that?
Here's my header's markup and css:

```
.top-bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: #FFF;
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.is-sticky {
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 72px;
}
```

Here the markup:

```
<div id="undefined-sticky-wrapper" class="sticky-wrapper is-sticky" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="top-bar" style="position: fixed; top: 0px;">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/" title="MyLogo">
                <img class="site-logo" src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/logo.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class=" nav-menu">
                    <li class="current_page_item">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2066">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/blog/">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="page_item page-item-2">
                        <a href="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/sample-page/">Homepage</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the css is simply

```
    .is-sticky{
      height: 10px;
     }

    .is-sticky .site-logo{
        height:8px;
    }
```

the "`.site-logo`" will now only get the `"height:8px"` when it has a parent of any level with class "`.is-sticky`"

---

*edit:*
Just saw OPs score. Am i misunderstanding the question?

Comment: Basically this was more of a transition-problem because animating an img's width/height property leads to strange spacing problems. Since I only require to support IE9 I went with the CSS3-transform-property. 
Your answer is still right and answers the question.